# Airflow - Unknown Blue Task Status

Tags: airflow

I just got a task colored in Blue which doesn't appear in the status legend. I'm curious if this is a bug or an undocumented status.

[image]

As you can see the color blue doesn't show up in the list of potential statuses on the right. I had just finished clearing all past, future, and upstream attempts fyi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a known TaskInstance State; it's just not on the UI -- it stands for `shutdown`:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/state.py#L70

Other statuses that don't appear on the upper right hand side include:

```
UPSTREAM_FAILED: 'orange'
REMOVED: 'lightgrey'
SCHEDULED: 'tan'
```

Answer (score 5):

Clearing a running task will often result in this color for a terminated/killed process. You just need to clear the task one additional time to reset it.