# Airflow Task got Shutdown Status after DAG is cleared

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Hi I tried to clear my DAG, however it turned later on my task got a *Shutdown Status* depicted in [blue state in Airflow Webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826900/airflow-unknown-blue-task-status). Is this an expected behavior? How can I avoid this after I clear my DAG?

Best!

Comment: If you tried to clear DAG, airflow usually shows this state. This might not a correct answer but if you clear the state again, it will rerun. I think they are waiting for killing response, but usually it stucks, so "double clear" strategy works for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Airflow has only [a tiny amount of documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Scheduler+Basics) for this state, but the blue `shutdown` status happens when a task has received a shutdown command from an external source. This usually happens when the airflow worker has received a kill signal. For example, during a deploy, you might kill the running worker to load the new code.

I'm not sure what you mean by clearing your DAG (do you mean when you clear a task from the Airflow UI?), but perhaps that sent a kill signal to the worker?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried to clear the task by using command line interface provided by airflow.

Comment: In that case, I suspect that clearing the task was incidental. When the task ran, it received a shutdown command. You should try to go through the logs to see where that command might have from - e.g. an external monitoring daemon that kills long-running processes.